# mysqldump forbidden syntax

Tags: mysql, wpmu

I am typing the following on the command line and trying to get a backup of the database that is on port 3306:

```
mysqldump -u[dbusername] --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 -p [dbname] > file.sql
```

but am getting a forbidden syntax error and just doesn't work even if I put the password in after -p arg.  I do not include the info for the brackets for security ofcourse, but trust me it's the right info in there minus the brackets.

Database Name has a hyphen and underscore in it.  Does this matter?  Do I need to escape these somehow?

Not sure if this matters, but site is hosted on WPMU.  What is wrong with the syntax here?

Comment: --h and port you can skip could you post the **complete message** can you write in that folder? where mysqldump resides. try a temp folder

Comment: It just says `***forbidden syntax:` and copies out the full command right after that that i used.

Comment: Do I have to escape hyphens in the database name somehow?

Comment: tried adding backticks to the database name, but that doesn't work either

Comment: database username also has a hyphen in it.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: that sound more like a os error than something of mysql.